# Yii - fetch data, where I am saved as an array values

Tags: php, database-design, yii

```
no  | name   | status
----+--------+---------
01  | karthi | 1,2,3,4 
02  | kuma   | 2,3,4
```

In the above table multi `status` values are stored into table.

I am using the following code, but its return empty value

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;

$criteria->compare = array("status"=>1);

$test    = Test::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

How can I fetch only `status` `1` value rows?

Comment: Follow normalization place that status (split it into single entity instead of comma separated) in separate table and mapped it with user id.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to having a related table. But you can do this with your solution. Just you need to explode value of status and get first item of result array. Something similar to this:

```
$statuses = explode(",", $status); //$status is "1,2,3,4" for example
$result = $statuses[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your values are separated with comma, you can just explode them into array and then check if needed value is in the array:

```
$searchValue = 1;
$statuses = explode(",", $status);
if (in_array($searchValue, $statuses)) {
   //your code here
}
```

PS: but as @hamed said, it is better database design to have a separated relation table for those data.